# XAMPP - Apache isn't Starting - Attempting to start apache service

Tags: apache, xampp

When I try to start the Apache Server, It shows the error shown below in the image.
I have checked everything twice but couldn't got anything.

[image: The Following error is shown]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also: See [ask] and mention what you tried already

Comment: Also what you need to copy is Apache logs, not XAMPP messages.

Comment: You have to at least check the logs before you ask.